# How to create a custom function to work with purrr or lapply?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner and would like to figure out how to not cut and paste 60 lines of code.
Here's my dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L),
            people = c("marge","homer","homer",
                       "homer","marge","bart","homer","homer","marge")
)
```

I tried to write a function so I could specify inputs to make this easier.
I actually want x to be a vector, but I can't even get this to work for a single observation.

```
lisaList <- function (x) {
    df[df$id==x, "people"] <- "lisa" 
}

#vector with the list of id's I want to change to "lisa"
myList=c(1,2,3)
```

things i tried that didn't work

```
lisaList(myList)
```

and this didn't work

```
lisaL <- function (x) {
   if(df$id==x) df[df$id==x, "people"] <- "lisa" }

lisaL(myList)
```

and i also tried to write something using mutate and then use purrr, but I also couldn't figure that out.

I want each observation in "id" which = 1, 2 or 3 to be changed to "lisa" so I end up with this

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L),
            people = c("lisa","lisa","lisa",
                       "homer","marge","bart","homer","homer","marge")
)
```

Thank you.

**Follow up to my original question**

Thank you both! These answers helped get me over a hurdle.
Now, I have 2 other questions which expand on this function, by adding another column to my df.
**Follow up question 1**
Now I want to be able to enter the observation that needs to be changed.

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L),
            people = c("bart","lisa","lisa",
                       "homer","marge","bart","homer","homer","marge"),
                                   pets = c("dog","wolf","horse",
                       "bat","mouse","mole","gopher","bat","bat")
)

# new function
list3 <- function(dat, x, y) {
    dat %>%
        mutate(people = replace(people,  id %in% x, y))
}

myList=c(3,4,5)

list3 (df, myList, 'cat')
```

This works okay, but is there something I can change within my function so the user wouldn't need to enter the observation with ' '?

I was able to achieve something close to what I want, but it requires creating a new list.

```
otherList <- c("ground hog")
list3 (df, myList, otherList)
```

**Follow up question 2**
Now I would like the user to be able to enter the column to be changed, instead of having the column name hard coded in the function. I've been trying to figure this out (which is why I thought I might try an alternative to using mutate in the function) but now I feel like I'm so close, I'd like to try to see how to do this.

So this first try didn't work.

```
list4 <- function(dat, x, y, z) {
    dat %>%
        mutate(z = replace(z,  id %in% x, y))
}

mycol <- c('pets')

list4(df, myList, 'birds', mycol)
```

And this didn't work.

```
list4 <- function(dat, x, y, z) {
    dat %>%
        mutate((enquo(z)) = replace( (!!z),  id %in% x, y))
}

mycol <- c('pets')
list4(df, myList, 'birds', mycol)
```

And many other versions trying to use {{ }} or specifying enquo ( ) and !!

Can you help me figure out how I can enter the column name? Thank you, both, again for your initial help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `%in%` instead of `==`

```
df$people[df$id %in% 1:3] <- "lisa"
```

So, the function would be

```
lisaL <- function (dat, x) {
           dat$people[dat$id %in% x] <- "lisa" 
           dat
         }


lisaL(df, myList)
#  id people
#1  1   lisa
#2  2   lisa
#3  3   lisa
#4  4  homer
#5  5  marge
#6  6   bart
#7  7  homer
#8  8  homer
#9  9  marge
```

---

Or using `replace` with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
lisaList2 <- function(dat, x) {
       dat %>%
                mutate(people = replace(people,  id %in% x, 'lisa'))
   }
```

---

If we want to use `==`, then an option is to loop over the 'myList' with `lapply` or a `for` loop, create a logical vector, `Reduce` it to single logical vector with `|` and assign

```
listList3 <- function(dat, x) {
    dat$people[Reduce(`|`, lapply(x, function(u) dat$id == u))] <- 'lisa'
    dat
    }
listList3(df, myList)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have edited my previous question to add 2 follow up questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `ifelse` in a `dplyr` pipe:

```
lisaList <- function (x) {
  df%>%
    mutate(people=ifelse(id %in% x,"lisa", people))
}

myList=c(1,2,3)

lisaList(myList)

id people
1  1   lisa
2  2   lisa
3  3   lisa
4  4  homer
5  5  marge
6  6   bart
7  7  homer
8  8  homer
9  9  marge
```

Regarding your third question, you can use `across` to specify a variable name within `mutate`. I've renamed the arguments to your function to help with readability:

```
list3 <- function(dat, rowindex, replacestring, colnamevar) {

  dat %>%
    mutate(across(colnamevar, ~ifelse(id %in% rowindex, replacestring, .)))
}

list3(df, myList, 'birds', mycol)

id people   pets
1  1   bart    dog
2  2   lisa   wolf
3  3   lisa  birds
4  4  homer  birds
5  5  marge  birds
6  6   bart   mole
```

Finally, don't know of a way to have R recognize an unquoted text as a string instead of a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have edited my previous question to add 2 follow up questions.

Comment: Ah, thank you, @Dealec! This is super helpful! I needed to make one small modification to get this to work  instead of  ` list3(df, myList, 'birds', mycol) ` I needed to add quotes around the mycol ` list3(df, myList, 'birds', 'mycol') `  I think I'm going too far down the rabbit hole worrying about quotes. In some respects the quotes make it a little easier to remember what should be changed when using the function. Thank you.

Comment: if `mycol` is defined as you have : `mycol <- 'pets'`, you shouldn't need to quote it, as it is a variable name. I should mention that you need to have your dplyr package updated (1.0.0) for the code to work.